# Calling another batch from the execute method of another batch

Tags: batch

Is it possible to initiate another batch from the Execute method of a running batch?

**My requirement:**

Users charge time to Timecards. At the end of the week I have a group of timecards (Timecard Header records) where time is charged to place holder projects. These place holder projects have child projects that are Billable projects. The time charged to these place holder projects should be distributed to all the active milestones of these child projects. Currently, I have a future method that takes the time from this timecard with the place holder project and distributes it the active milestones of the child projects by creating time card Header record for each of these active milestone/project combination. We are running into CPU time limit error when a place holder project has large no. of child projects.

In order to get around this problem I chose to implement this using batch apex. The idea is to have one batch apex batch1 to process these place holder timecards in batches of 1. Then in the Execute method of batch1, if the child project count > 50 then initiate batch2 from the Execute method to process 10 child projects at a time.

Comment: I dont think you can do that. You can chain batches by calling the second batch in the `future` method of the first one but in the `execute()` it would run totally differently, and quite likely you would hit the governor limits.

Comment: Did you profile the code to see if you could solve the time limit error? Could be a small change is all that's needed

Comment: @Eric. yes I did. The problem is that a manager could approve around 10 place holder timecards. The place holder project in each of these timecards could have 100 child projects . All this is now being processed in a future method and hence running into cpu time limit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't execute a separate batch anywhere other than the finish method. However, you are allowed a single System.enqueueJob call that you could use to process the data using a Queueable class. This queueable class can chain itself indefinitely (in production) to use as much CPU time as it pleases (but there will be delays between each successive chain to limit resource usage).

Comment: So are you suggesting to use a combination of batch and Queueable class? Could I make this call in the Execute method of the batch class

Comment: @Neema Yes, you are allowed a single Queueable call per Batchable and Queueable execute method, so you can jump to a Queueable from your Batchable, then chain that as many times as you need to complete your processing.

Comment: Thank you. That is very helpful. I would just like to confirm that once the chained Queueable completes processing , the execution will continue with the original batch until the next time the Queueable call is made.  In this manner the execution jumps between batch and queueable successfully. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Neema No. The Batchable will not wait for the Queueable, but continue processing the next execute method. The Queueable will run in parallel to the batch.

Comment: ok. Thank You. If the Batchable continues with processing the next Execute method,  the next Execute method could call the Queueable again, correct? What I am trying to get at is that during the execution of the entire batch, I wont run into any limits even if each Execute method makes a call to the Queueable?

Comment: @Neema No, you'll be okay; each additional Queueable will wait its turn to run.

Comment: Thank You. I appreciate all the help. I will try this and let you know

Comment: After all the Child projects are processed with in a timecard(This is when I chain using the queueable class ), I need to set a field(Allocated__c) to true on the timecard. Is there a way to implement something similar to the Database.Stateful as in Batch apex and accumulate a count since I am queueing the same class? Another thought I had was to create a custom object and write any errors to this object for each Queueable in the chain. Then query this object at the end of the chain . If no errors found then set the field to true on the timecard.